# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting error python

Tags: python

I have customized tempest code for our REST API's, but when i run the scripts, using nosetests at the beginning it gives some weird type error as mentioned below, though test cases in the script passes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py",line 776, in emit msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 654, in format return fmt.format(record)
  File "/home/rmcbuild/repository/rmc-test/tempest/openstack/common/log.py", line 516, in format return logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage msg = msg % self.args
 TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

has anyone come across this type of error, would appreciate if someone helps me out of it.

Thanks,

Comment: Was there any possible solution u found? I am encountering the same problem as well (I know this post is quite old. But just incase if ur solution could help me)

Answer (score 14):

This happens when using `%s` to print a string:

```
>>> x = 'aj8uppal'
>>> print 'Hello, %s %s' %(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> print 'Hello, ' %(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>>
```

If you put one too many `%s`s, it gives a `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`, but if you put one to few, it gives `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

What is likely is that you have put a variable(s) in parentheses at the end, but the number of percent signs does not match. Please post your code if you want us to help you further :)

Comment: My code doesn't have any `%s`s and I'm still getting this message from logging

Answer (score -1):

I received this error when I typed a '&s' by mistake rather than a '%s'

Comment: This is not an answer, comment it on the question if you think it can help him.